# How do I make this python code a one liner?

Tags: python, simplify, one-liner

```py
for _ in line:
    if line == "t":
        t += 1  
    else:
        s += 1
```

How do I make this python code a one liner?

Comment: What are `t` and `s` originally? Also are you sure this code actually does what you want it to?

Comment: originally, t = 0 and s = 0

Answer (score 1):

```
def bar(line):
    t = s = 0
    for _ in line:
        if line == "t":
            t += 1  
        else:
            s += 1
    return t, s
```

is equivalent to:

```
def foo(line):
    t, s = (1, 0) if line == "t" else (0, len(line))
    return t, s
```

Test it out:

```
import random
NUM_TESTS = 100
MAX_STR_LEN = 10

def get_rand_chs(l):
    for _ in range(l):
       o = random.randint(ord('a'), ord('z'))
       yield chr(o)

def get_rand_str():
    l = random.randint(0, MAX_STR_LEN)
    return ''.join(ch for ch in get_rand_chs(l))

for _ in range(NUM_TESTS):
    rand_str = get_rand_str()
    print(f'Testing {rand_str!r}...')
    assert bar(rand_str) == foo(rand_str)
```

---

Note: OP, what you probably meant to do was:

```
def bar(line):
    t = s = 0
    for _ in line:
        if _ == "t":
            t += 1  
        else:
            s += 1
    return t, s
```

If that's the case, then all that `t` does is count the number of `"t"`s and `s` counts the other characters, which can be done in two lines:

```
def foo(line):
    t = line.count("t")
    s = len(line) - t
    return t, s
```

It can of course be done in one line, if you don't mind calling `line.count("t")` twice.

Per @kaya3's comment, here's a more compact alternative:

```
def foo(line):
    s = len(line) - (t := line.count("t"))
    return t, s
```

FYI, the same test code can be used to verify they are equivalent.

Comment: @KetZoomer I'm not sure what you think `len(line)` can be, other than 1, if `line == "t"` is true.

Comment: @KetZoomer exactly what kaya3 said. Not sure why this is downvoted. This is exactly equivalent to what OP wrote. I'm writing some tests for it right now.

Comment: I didn't downvote, and I agree that this answer is the only one that's equivalent to the OP's code. But I also didn't upvote, because I don't think this is actually what the OP wants to do - it seems more likely their code is wrong to start with - and I suspect that may be the reason somebody downvoted. Either way, the question needs to be improved, either to fix the code so that it does what OP wants, or to confirm that this is in fact what OP wants.

Comment: @kaya3 I updated my answer to include the alternative.

Comment: OK, I've now upvoted; by the way, you can do it in one line without calling `.count` twice if you use an assignment expression like `s = len(line) - (t := line.count("t"))`.

Comment: Ah, good to know. I wasn't sure if I could use the walrus operator outside if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
ts=(len([x for x in line if x=="t"]),len([x for x in line if x!="t"]))
```

Two generator statements that go through `line` and create a list with the letters that are or are not `"t"`, then surrounding each with `len` and some brackets around both to create a tuple in `ts`. The variables `t` and `s` can be assigned like `ts[0]` and `ts[1]`.

Comment: The original code checks if `line` itself is equal to "t", not if each _element_ of line is equal to "t".

Comment: @JohnGordon aah, sorry. Didn't see that.

Comment: Also why use list comprehensions? Python has a `list.count` function. This is the opposite of pythonic.

Comment: @VivekUpadhyay you could assign `t` and `s` like `t,s=ts`

Comment: @Nick sorry, I didn't realise that there was a `list.count` function. Also, This is just the way I would do it

Answer (score 0):

How about using count()? `line.count("t")` will return the number of times string "t" appear in the line? Note that, the variable `t` got unpack first so that `len(line) - t`, which will be assigned to `s`, can be used at the time of assingment.

```
>>> line = "ttttttseeeee"
>>> t, s = line.count("t"), len(line) - t
>>> t
6
>>> s
8
```

Comment: jfyi, `s` counts the number of non-`"t"` characters.

Comment: Sorry for that, I updated the post